# Arduino API and Json sending information to azure

Tags: json, azure, arduino

I am new to arduino programming and I was wondering if I could use Arduino API's and Json to send information stored on an Arduino Uno to Azure, For example my Arduino board is meant to have  a person's name and their ID number which When they press the button they send their name and ID to the Azure tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use Azure [Table Service REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179423.aspx). Details of how to insert entity to table [can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd894033.aspx):

> The Insert Entity operation sends the entity to be inserted as an
>   OData entity, which is either a JSON or an Atom feed

it's not completely straight forward ( you have to handle authentication and build [OData entity](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/json-format/)) but it's possible.

Have a look at this - [Connecting the Arduino Uno to Azure Mobile Services](http://hypernephelist.com/2014/07/11/arduino-uno-azure-mobile-services.html). This does not use Table Service REST API but principle is the same